# Compiler errors in standard C library headers in VS2015 - Visual C++ Console Application project

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

I recently created a VS2015 solution to continue development on a C++ project I had been working on. Whenever I try to build the project, I get hundreds of errors from standard C library header files such as string.h, stdio.h, etc.

To try to get to the root of the problem, I created a new, very basic, VC++ win32 console application project, wondering if I'd see the same compiler errors.  Here is the code (ConsoleApplication1.cpp):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "some data to print...";
    std::cout << "Printing: " << s.c_str()  << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I attempt to compile this, I get 150+ errors, like this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  stdafx.cpp
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(309): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(309): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(311): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(311): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(311): error C2086: 'int _CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE': redefinition
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(309): note: see declaration of '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(317): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(317): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(317): error C2086: 'int _CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE': redefinition
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(309): note: see declaration of '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(320): error C2144: syntax error: 'int' should be preceded by ';'
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(320): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(320): error C2086: 'int _CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE': redefinition
1>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\stdio.h(309): note: see declaration of '_CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE'

....etc
```

I have tried to 'repair' Microsoft VC++ 2015 Redistributable(x86) via the Windows 'Uninstall or change a program' utility, to no avail.  I also tried to repair Visual Studio 2015 as a whole.

I'm on Windows 7.

Anyone have an idea what is going on here?  Am I pointed to the wrong include directory or something?

Comment: If you have precompiled headers on you need to include that file first.  The default name for it is stdafx.h.

Comment: `stdafx.cpp` in the output would seem to indicate that some part of the project is using precompiled headers.

Comment: Just a note: reparing the VC redist doesn't help with issues like this, afaik the redistributable consists of only dlls, no header files.

Comment: There's a "stdafx.cpp" included in the project, OP isn't including "stdafx.h" in the main source.  The errors are coming from compiling "stdafx.cpp", not the main source shown in the post.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I just realized that the project I posted was the one with precompiled headers on.  I've updated to question to reflect this.  Either way, I believe the same problem occurs in both cases.

Answer (score -1):

It appears you have (some of) the headers from a previous version of VS installed in your VS2015 folder.  The standard headers in VS2015 are stored off in a folder tied to the version of the CRT (something like `c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt`).  Repairing or reinstalling VS2015 won't fix this.

I think you'll need to uninstall VS2015, completely delete the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0`, then reinstall it.  This will likely break the other version (VS2013?) that is installed there, so you might want/need to uninstall that version instead, then repair VS2015.

The  header that comes with VS2015 does not appear to have the "int _CRTIMP_ALTERNATIVE" listed in some of the error messages at those lines, while the one with VS2013 does.

Comment: I also have VS 2008 installed, but wouldn't those headers be placed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0` ?  I need 2008 still for some legacy projects.

Comment: @Sam They should be.  I was looking at my various installs and this is my  guess where your error is coming from.

Comment: @dan what exactly do you mean?  create a new win32 console application project, copy + paste the code into there and try a build?

Comment: @ Ðаn Just tried, no I get the same errors.  Also tried to import a project into VS2015 that built fine in VS2008 and got the same types of errors on the project.  For the record, I have not previously tried VC++ development in 2015 on this machine